# How can I return data from my table grouped but still in order of title?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I've got a simple table in a SQL Server 2012 database and I'm querying the table using EntityFramework 6 in ASP.Net 4.51. The table has the following structure and data...

```
FileID       GroupID     Title             DateAdded
------------------------------------------------------
1            1           Charlie rev 1     21/05/2016
2            2           Beta rev 1        22/05/2016
3            1           Charlie rev 2     23/05/2016
4            2           Beta rev 2        24/05/2016
5            3           Alpha rev 1       25/05/2016
```

Basically the table represents files and revisions of files uploaded by the user, so when they view the data I'm wanting to show the first file of a group, then all older revisions in descending date order below.  Ordering by `GroupID` and `DateAdded Descending`, I can get the following...

```
FileID       GroupID     Title             DateAdded
--------------------------------------------------------
3            1           Charlie rev 2     23/05/2016
1            1           Charlie rev 1     21/05/2016
4            2           Beta rev 2        24/06/2016
2            2           Beta rev 1        22/05/2016
5            3           Alpha rev 1       25/05/2016
```

While this is close to what I'm after, I'd rather have the titles in alphabetical order first, then all the revisions (by group) in descending date order.

**I'm looking for this output**:

```
FileID       GroupID     Title             DateAdded
-----------------------------------------------------
5            3           Alpha rev 1       25/05/2016
4            2           Beta rev 2        24/05/2016
2            2           Beta rev 1        22/05/2016
3            1           Charlie rev 2     23/05/2016
1            1           Charlie rev 1     21/05/2016
```

I can achieve this with two tables, but I'm ideally looking for a solution using the table I currently have.

Can anyone help with a **Linq** statement that will produce this output?

In short, I think what i'm asking for is to sort the table by the first most recent Title of each group (by descending date order) then by the remaining items of each group by descending date order.

Thanks in advance for your help,

**Edit:** to satisfy posters who want 'shown effort', I know that the following Linq statement will work to produce the first result.

```
var result = context.MyTable.OrderBy(x => x.GroupID)
                            .ThenByDescending(x => x.DateAdded);
```

As for the second result... I wouldn't be posting if I knew how to achieve it.  I'm not new to SQL but I am new to this particular problem. It isn't homework and I've spent a number of hours trying to figure it out. As stated, I already have this working using two tables but it should be achievable with one.

Comment: Show your effort.

Comment: I think the OP means grouping by partial string, so `Alpha rev`, then `Beta rev` etc (with the number extracted from the title & sorted descending). The GroupID seems rather irrelevant but it may still count.

Comment: You say you want the file names in alphabetical order, but your sample data has no such column.

Comment: Apologies, I mean by Title.  I'll get it changed.

Comment: Will the `Title` columns *always* be formatted as `Some text rev #`, with emphasis on `rev #`? Or are there `Title` values such as `Beta ver 3` or `Charlie first`?

Comment: Have you tried context.MyTable.OrderBy(x => x.GroupID).ThenBy(x => x.Title).ThenByDescending(x => x.DateAdded);

Comment: The title can be anything at all. I just used those examples so it was easier to see the hierarchy of the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In short, I think what i'm asking for is to sort the table by the first most recent Title of each group (by descending date order) then by the remaining items of each group by descending date order.

There are several way you can accomplish this in LINQ to Objects. However LINQ to Entities supports limited number of constructs, so I would suggest you using a direct translation of the above explanation:

```
var result = context.MyTable
    .OrderBy(t => context.MyTable
        .Where(t1 => t1.GroupId == t.GroupId)
        .OrderByDescending(t1 => t1.DateAdded)
        .Select(t1 => t1.Title)
        .FirstOrDefault())
    .ThenByDescending(t => t.DateAdded);
```

Comment: As this is for a view model, your solution is perfect. Many thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

If your logic always compose `Title` as `FileName + "rev" + revision.Version` then you can just order values by that value instead of `GroupId`.

But you'll need to use  [`AsEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435(v=vs.110).aspx) to switch to LINQ to Objects before `OrderBy`. This will cause that your query will execute without ordering and returns data to the client and then will order on client side.

Next query will return data as in the last table:

```
var result = context
                 .MyTable
                 .AsEnumerable()
                 .OrderBy(x => x.GetFileName())
                 .ThenByDescending(x => x.DateAdded);
```

However, this will not give the expected word if the input string only has one word, so a special case is needed. But if you have always use pattern above then this is enough for your reasons.

If you need to have [`IQueryable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562(v=vs.110).aspx) result then you can implement a stored procedure to retrieve substring from `Title` field:

```
var result = context
                 .MyTable
                 .AsEnumerable()
                 .OrderBy(x => x.Title.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(" "))
                 .ThenByDescending(x => x.DateAdded);
```

Comment: No, this will put `Alpha rev 1` *before* `Alpha rev 2`

Comment: @user1429080 my fail. Fixed answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sadly the title can be anything at all. The groupID is the key here. To explain, a user will upload a file and give it a title of anything they want. Then later they will possibly upload a revision to that file which could have a different title. The groupid is used to keep all the files together so I know consequent additions are revisions of the file. As I said, I can get it working but wanted output to be in alphabetical order for the most recent file in each group.

Answer (score 1):

Using plain old `SQL` this could be a starting point:

```
declare @t table (FileId int, GroupId int, Title varchar(50), DateAdded datetime)
insert into @t 
    select       1, 1, 'Charlie rev 1', '2016-05-21'
    union select 2, 2, 'Beta rev 1',    '2016-05-22'
    union select 3, 1, 'Charlie rev 2', '2016-05-23'
    union select 4, 2, 'Beta rev 2',    '2016-05-24'
    union select 5, 3, 'Alpha rev 1',   '2016-05-25'

select t.*
from @t t
    join (
        select GroupId, min(Title) as mtitle from @T group by GroupId
    ) subt on t.GroupId = subt.GroupId
order by subt.mtitle, t.GroupId, t.DateAdded desc
```

But I can't off the top of my head write the equivalent `Linq`.

The plain old `SQL` sample works by picking one `Title` value (in this case the `MIN`value) from a group and uses that as a representative for the whole group for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a try and here is a solution I stubled across. However, due to lack of time I didn't test it for mor than the provided test data. Feel free to comment.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
  FileID int
 ,GroupID int
 ,Title nvarchar(50)
 ,DateAdded date
);

INSERT INTO @t VALUES(1, 1, 'Carlie rev 1', '2016-05-21'), (2, 2, 'Beta rev 1', '2016-05-22'),
                     (3, 1, 'Carlie rev 2', '2016-05-23'), (4, 2, 'Beta rev 2', '2016-05-24'),
                     (5, 3, 'Alpha rev 1', '2016-05-25');

WITH cte1 AS(                    
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY title ASC) AS rn0, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateAdded DESC) AS rn1
    FROM @t
),
cte2 AS(
SELECT *, rn0*rn1 AS rn3
  FROM cte1
)
SELECT FileID, GroupID, Title, DateAdded FROM cte2
  ORDER BY rn3
```

Comment: Just for additional information: I just did another test with additional records - seemingly, there are combinations, which lead to a wrong result. :-( My additional records were (6,1,'Alpha rev 2', '2016-04-22') and (1, 2, 'Zulu rev 1', '2016-11-25'). I will keep on trying to modify the solution